# How can I assign the max value of a subquery into a variable in SQL

Tags: sql, variables, max

My issue is that it marks an error on `SELECT` on `SET @Maximo` and I don't understand why

```
DECLARE @Maximo int 
SET @Maximo = SELECT MAX(A.[Count Equipo])
              FROM 
                  (SELECT 
                       E.IdEquipo, E.Nombre, COUNT(E.IdEquipo) AS 'Count Equipo', 
                       SUM(GolesL) AS 'Gol local', SUM(GolesV) AS 'Gol Vis'
                   FROM 
                       Jornada J
                   LEFT JOIN 
                       Equipo E ON E.IdEquipo = J.Equipo_Local OR E.IdEquipo = J.Equipo_Visitante
                   GROUP BY
                       E.IdEquipo, E.Nombre) A
```

This subquery is supposed to print out a 4 which is what I need to assign to the `@Maximo` variable.

Comment: Why guessing like "is supposed to..."? Just execute the query and verify if it really returns 4. You should always verify that your query gives the intendes result before using it.

Comment: If it's SQL Server (and possibly others) you need brackets around the whole select e.g., `SET @Maximo = (SELECT ...)` see https://dbfiddle.uk/qBiZaBeE for example.

Comment: Please use bracket to group whole select statement .. Should be SET @Maximo = (SELECT ....)

Comment: Try using `SELECT @Maximo = MAX(.....)` - no need for `SET` and `SELECT` together ....

Comment: @marc_s - SET and SELECT variable names do act differently in how they handle no results (SELECT keeps the previous value). It's not needed in this specific code (as the variable is defined right before, so it is already NULL; also MAX() will always return a result, even if NULL). However, sometimes you need the SET and SELECT together. See https://dbfiddle.uk/YiZ2zNRR for an example.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code is product specific.